# Data Annotations not working

Tags: silverlight-4.0, data-annotations

I am new to Silverlight 4.0 building a business application.   I have tried ussing some of the Data Annotation attributes with both the DataForm and the DataGrid.  The Display and Editable attributes work without a problem, but DisplayFormat seems to be ignored.  Am I missing something or are these attributes not supported by the DataGrid and DataForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayFormat is not picked up by the Silverlight controls.  If you wanted to control the display format you could either use the StringFormat on the Binding or a custom converter built against the IValueConverter interface.  Most likely you will do something like this:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Binding="{Binding Path=Cost, StringFormat=\{0:c\}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you.  This will greatly aid our efforts.